# netstat shows too many established connections in windows

Tags: netstat

I have an Internet service by ADSL, the problem is that my download speed has decreased dramatically in the order of 60 or 70% down. One friend recommend me to put netstat -an on a terminal window and I got the following results:

[image]

The problem is that my actual IP is:

[image]

One quick question appears here, is it not suppose that the Local Address:

xxx.168.1.34 should match my ip xxx.43.236.168?

In any case, I was blaming my ISP because of the decrease of my internet speed, but my technician friend told me that maybe I have some trojans that are making these connections.

The weird thing is that when I boot my PC with Linux I only got two ESTABLISHED connections, and the internet speed has the same values as its windows counterpart.

**Update info:** I have applied netstat -an to see the established connections under Linux (I have both operating systems on my PC) and these are the results:

[image]

In both cases I am accessing thru the Internet using a wired connection, the wireless is deactivated.

What could it be going wrong? Should I change of ISP?
Help, please

Comment: You are connecting to compute-1.amazonaws.com. Do you use Amazon AWS services?

Comment: @DavidPostill, no that I know, well I had a subscription to prime, but it was cancelled. How can I get rid of the established connections?

Comment: Start by finding out what process is making the connections. [Is there any way to find out what programs are trying to connect to Internet on windows?](//superuser.com/q/222329)

Comment: First check the above advise. Do you use wireless or ethernet to connect to the router-modem ? Maybe a restart of the router would solve the problem.

Comment: @GiaRui I am using a ethernet conection

Comment: It depends if the connections are using much bandwidth(downloading/uploading). On linux it seems that a firefox-session is open and connect to the mentioned ip's/webaddresses, perhaps on windows too (netstat -anop). You could also try a speed-test e.g. https://www.cnet.com/internet-speed-test/ or some equivalent site of your internet-provider.

Comment: On what basis do you claim the number of connections is "too many"? It looks pretty normal to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem to yours. I just called the customer service of my ISP and they ordered me to do `netstat -n -o`, then I found too many `ESTABLISHED` connections. The agent said that this is the problem of my weak bandwidth and I must have my PC clean from viruses and malwares.

I run [Tcpview software](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) and as you see the result in the image. Here is many `ESTABLISHED` connections but it belongs to some apps running on windows or some system processes. So, I didn't think that it is the cause of the problem. Now, my internet speed is good although there are still too many established connections on my PC.

I just wanted to share my experience and with it will help.

[image: from Tcpview software]